# Align website logo to repeating background squares on banner across different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am having issues aligning the logo of my [website in progress](http://nick11roberts.github.io/) to the repeating background of the banner. I intend for it to align (on hover, you can see the button's background) to the background tiles, just as the buttons on the right do, except I want it to be measured from the left side of the screen so that it be more toward the left. 
I tried adding `padding-left:1286px;` to the css, but if I do that, it will jump off of the screen on different screen widths, so I thought I probably needed to use a variable `padding-right` which would be modified by javascript when it's first displayed. In order to try that, I tried

```
var htmlWidth = $( document ).width();          
var paddingAmt = htmlWidth - 200;
document.getElementById("logoContainer").style.paddingLeft=paddingAmt;
```

but that didn't do anything at all, no matter how I modified it (I used it as an external script, and an embedded script, and I didn't forget to include jQuery at the top of my HTML doc). If I could get that script to work in the way I wanted it to, I would do arithmetic on the `htmlWidth` variable to determine exactly how many tiles/partial tiles (in pixels) to subtract from `htmlWidth` so that it aligns snugly with a tile.

Here is the css for the logo and it's container:

```
#logoContainer{
    padding-right:200px;
}

#logoImg{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    min-height:15px;
    max-height:65px;
    width:99px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-top:10px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */ 

    transition: box-shadow .25s ease-in-out, background .1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow .25s ease-in-out, background .1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .25s ease-in-out, background .1s ease-in-out;  
}
```

and here is the css for the banner:

```
#menuBar{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height: 55px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    background-image:url('../images/invertTile.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    border-bottom: 10px #efe8e3 solid;
    border-bottom-width: 10px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #efe8e3;   

    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out, border-bottom .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out, border-bottom .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out, border-bottom .25s ease-in-out;

}
```

and here is the html for the banner and it's buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "js/logoplacement.js"></script>

<div id="menuBar" onmouseover="ifScrolledOpacityShift ()" onmouseout="scroll ()" >

    <div id="logoContainer">

        <a id="logoLink" href="index.html">

            <img id="logoImg" src= "images/logo.png"  />

        </a>

    </div>




    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------- BUTTONS -->

    <div class="buttons" id="button1">

        <a class="buttonLinks" id="buttonLink1" href="#">

            <img class="buttonImgs" id="buttonImg1" src= "images/breadButton.png"  />

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="buttons" id="button2">

        <a class="buttonLinks" id="buttonLink2" href="#">

            <img class="buttonImgs" id="buttonImg2" src="images/breadButton.png"  />

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="buttons" id="button3">

        <a class="buttonLinks" id="buttonLink3" href="#">

            <img class="buttonImgs" id="buttonImg3" src="images/breadButton.png"  />

        </a>

    </div>

    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------- /BUTTONS -->


</div>
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working and I can't think of any other way to do this. Is there an easier way, or a way to fix my broken javascript?

Comment: Have you tried adding the 'right' css property (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_right.asp) for alignment already?

Comment: Yes, I tried it in the javascript for the logo container but it didn't do anything differently.